# How to capture a cell's output for use in another cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In org-mode, I can name the output of a code block and include it elsewhere in the document.
Is it possible to do this (or something similar) in a colab .ipynb file, or within a Jupyter notebook in general?

For example, I can make a cell with some Python code that generates a plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,2,1,4,9])
```

After executing, the plot appears below the code cell. So far so good.
**But how do I capture this plot and to use it elsewhere in the notebook?**

My hope is there is some syntax so that I can include the plot in a markdown cell, for example:

```
# this is my title
As you can see, the numbers go up and down in the plot:

![][some_magic_link_here]

Here is some more text to explain the plot.
```

Does such a feature exist in colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news - embedding an image in another markdown cell is self-service. Here's an example:

[image]

Full notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PF-hT-m8eZN2CBzFkMp9Bvzj9pSBQVYn

The key bits are:

1. Using `IPython.display.Markdown` is order to programmatically construct the markdown.
2. In addition to rendering, save the matplotlib figure using `savefig`.
3. Include the image data in the markdown after `base64` encoding.

Comment: That's disappointing, but then again I'm spoiled by org-mode.